Not able to Jumpstart Sagemaker
I am just getting started with AWS and Sakemaker. I am just getting ResourceLimitExceeded error on everything I do.
I have tried 2 things: 1) create a domain and 2) create a notebook. I am getting the same error msg.
Additional info:

I want to use us-west-1, but it auto set me to Virginia from time to
time.
I have tried to use I am user gesong and the root user, either works.
I have create my AWS account and the I am user around 10 years, but
never used it after creating them. Anything I have to do to reset
it?

Please let me know if you need anything else.

If you get the ResourceLimitExceeded errors, its highly likely that you do not have the quotas to create these resources. To fix this, go to Service Quotas on your AWS console (make sure you're in us-west-1), choose Amazon SageMaker as the service, and check for the limits for Total domains, Maximum number of Studio user profiles allowed per account for Studio, Total number of notebook instances for notebook instances etc.
Also, check the instance type you're trying to use - ones like the ml.t3 or ml.m5 family instances would have default limits >0, whereas GPU instances would need to be requested through the Service Quotas console.
